How to display a time table in ics format with Pandas+Python then to merge several ics after pivot tables?
I have several ics files containing weekly time tables. I can load one:
from icalendar import Calendar
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import os

def events_to_dataframe(events):
    data = []

    for event in events:
        summary = event.get('summary')
        start = event.get('dtstart').dt
        end = event.get('dtend').dt

        # Récupération des champs
        fields = summary.split(";")
        # state = fields[0]
        # class_name = fields[1]
        # room = fields[2]

        data.append({
            'Hour': start.strftime("%H:%M") + " - " + end.strftime("%H:%M"),
            'Room': room,
            'State': state,
            'Sequence': ''
        })

    return pd.DataFrame(data)

# Ouvrir et lire le fichier s35.ics
with open('s35.ics', 'rb') as ics_file:
    ics_content = ics_file.read()

calendar = Calendar.from_ical(ics_content)
print(Calendar.property_items(calendar))

# Stocker les événements de chaque classe dans un dictionnaire
class_events = defaultdict(list)

# for event in calendar.walk('VEVENT'):
#     summary = event.get('summary')
#     class_name = summary.split(";")
#     class_events[class_name].append(event)
print(type(class_events))
print(class_events.keys())

How can I display it using Pandas with its view as a time table?
The aim is to make, possibly with pivot tables, a table with date/hours as line and courses as column with classroom number as content or empty.
